# How to convert response data into string in Xcode6

Tags: swift

I downloaded Xcode6 and tried a project with NSUrlConnection.
How do i convert response data into string in Xcode6?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var outputString:NSString = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Or if you want a `String`: `var outputString: String = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)`